# Moving to a section within the same page in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 6.1. I have a  section in my code. I am using an anchor tag to point to that div. Here my problem is when I click on the link, it's moving to the next section instead of the actual. It is pointing to the section below the actual div. Below is my code

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8">
         <div class="sec3 pad-rem">
      
            <div class="data py-5 pad-rem1" id="hello">
              <h1>
                <strong>"Hello"</strong>
              </h1>
            </div>
    

           <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between">
             <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
               <%= image_tag "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" %>
               <br><br>
                <div class="card description-card">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      It is a long-established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here, making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many websites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humor and the like).
                  </div>
               </div>
               <a href="#hello">Click me</a>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on 'click me' in the following image,

[image]

It should go to the "Hello" section

[image]

But unfortunately, it's going to a place below the "Hello"

[image]

The same code in normal HTML working very fine but when it comes to rails html.erb file, it's exhibiting the above behavior

SCSS:

```
 .wrapper{background-color: #0e2a47;padding: 7px 10px;position: sticky;z-index: 333;top: 0;}


 .sec3{padding: 40px 0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #dae1e9;.data{ p{color: #90a1b8;}  }
```

Comment: Update your code with the styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with z-index, So remove the following styles from the wrapper

```
    position: sticky;z-index: 333;top: 0;
```